# Flash Video Players: Do people really use the volume control?

Tags: flash, video, audio, volume

Im wondering if anyone has any input on this subject? Im building a flash video player, and I have added a mute volume icon, but Im wondering what everyone's thoughts are on adding a volume control too?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I consider a volume control to be an absolute requirement. Your idea of "normal levels" may be drastically different than mine. Besides, you may want to hear some of the moaning and squealing without sharing it with everyone else in your cube farm.

Comment: I second that. I actually find myself going to volume control first thing when loading up a flash video.

Comment: I also second that.  Or third it, however you want to look at it. ;)

Comment: It's easier to use a flash player's volume control than reaching across my desk for the physical volume or clicking around my system tray to find where my volume icon is hiding.  I agree that it's critical to video & audio playback in a Flash UI.

Comment: +1. Flash players that assume you want to hear everything at FULL VOLUME are super-annoying and one of the reasons I use FlashBlock.

Comment: I agree, there should always be an option to change sound levels

Comment: Moaning and squealing? Is this about what I think it is?

Comment: I wasn't referring to improper behavior with barnyard animals, were you? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I Hate it personnaly when the embedded video is way to loud, and I have no direct way to control the output of the source.

I guess the more control you give to the users the more problems you might face....

Answer (score 0):

The mute is the only volume control I ever use on one of those things. That said, unless you are purposefully trying to be innovative and different, I would provide a regular volume control too, even though it might not get used much. It's effectively a standard, expected control on one of those players by now, and subverting user expectations is never a good idea. No reason to annoy those few folks who might actually want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example, I use a digital audio cable from my MacBook Pro to my receiver so I don't have a systemwide volume control. Sometimes I'll have the volume set very loud for watching a movie, and although the receiver isn't far away it's still easier to change the application volume setting instead.